# CakePHP 3: Accessing trait from controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I access a method from trait in a controller in CakePHP 3?
Or is doing this against the Cake design paradigm?

I have tried the following

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Traits;
class UsersController extends AppController{
  use Traits\CommonTrait;
  public function index()
  {
    $this->Common->traitMethod();
  }
}
```

But I am getting

> Call to a member function... on boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a trait, your class will have access to the functions of the trait.

```
$this->traitMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a change in your code.

See how use Traits and its methods:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Traits\CommonTrait;

class UsersController extends AppController{

  use CommonTrait;

  public function index()
  {
    $this->traitMethod();
  }
}
```